# Read Modem Firmware Version : Android

Tags: java, android, android-firmware

I am working on an application which is in iPhone and Android, where I need to read `Modem Firmware Version` as iPhone developer does in his side.

I searched on Internet/SO but couldn't find anything related to my problem.

***Is it possible to read `Modem Firmware Version` in Android? If not what should be equivalent to that?*** (We read this attribute and more for keeping track of a device)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As nandeesh said to use baseband version at the place of Modem firmware, he didn't provided any source code of his custom method.

*I did some RnD and got final solution as*

```
private static final String BASEBAND_VERSION = "gsm.version.baseband";

/**
     * Returns a SystemProperty
     *
     * @param propName The Property to retrieve
     * @return The Property, or NULL if not found
     */
    public static String getSystemProperty(String propName) {
        String TAG = "TEst";
        String line;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop " + propName);
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()), 1024);
            line = input.readLine();
            input.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to read sysprop " + propName, ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception while closing InputStream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return line;
    }
```

and call it as

```
String basebandVersion = getSystemProperty(BASEBAND_VERSION);
```

All credits goes to [cyanogen-updater](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogen-updater/source/checkout) , custom method taken from this same project [SysUtils](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogen-updater/source/browse/trunk/src/cmupdaterapp/utils/SysUtils.java)

Answer (score 2):

The about phone on android shows the baseband version by getting the property gsm.version.baseband . You can use SystemProperties.get("gsm.version.baseband","unknown");

Comment: is this same as modem version?