# API call to get processor architecture

Tags: android, cpu-architecture

As part of my app I'm using the NDK and was wondering if it's worth bundling x86 and mips binaries alongside the standard ARM binaries.

I figured the best way would be to track what my users actually have, is there an API call to grab the processor architecture so I can pass this back to my Google analytics instance?

Thanks

Comment: If you just put ARM binaries, will the other architectures be able to download it? http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/publishing-your-android-application-on-the-android-market/

Comment: No ,  it will support only supported binaries based on architecture.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Actually, you can get the architecture without the need for reflexion at all:

```
String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

From my tests it returned `armv71` and `i686`.

EDIT:

On MIPS architecture, it either returns 'mips' or 'mips64'

On 64 bit ARM/Intel, it returns 'aarch64' or 'x86_64' respectively.

Comment: What does it return for MIPS-based processors?

Comment: I've believe it returns "mips", can't remember if I actually tested in the emulator. But that's what I use.

Comment: Just to make things right- I'm getting 'armv7l' and not 'arm71' as you said. any reason that you can think of?

Comment: THat's why I check only on "arm" because it varies from device to device

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a compile-time-constant here so any conditionals that depends on it can be optimized away at compile time?  Not a big deal if this is in a JIT-compiled language, though.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this returns the **JRE**'s architecture, not the underlying system architecture. However, on Android, these will pretty much always match because of how the system is integrated with Java, and as such all the current answers should return the same architecture.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `aarch64`, not `arch64`?

Comment: *Processor architecture is a runtime information* I think 2 years ago I didn't realize this was a Java question.  The OP was talking about making x86 binaries vs. MIPS binaries, so clearly they are making different binaries for different platforms, and thus could make it a compile-time constant if they had different builds of this code for every platform.

Comment: in emulator I got i686.how to get all values? It maybe armv71 or others.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use android SDK, take a look on the `Build` class:

```
    /** The name of the instruction set (CPU type + ABI convention) of native code. */
    public static final String CPU_ABI = getString("ro.product.cpu.abi");

    /** The name of the second instruction set (CPU type + ABI convention) of native code. */
    public static final String CPU_ABI2 = getString("ro.product.cpu.abi2");
```

Comment: way better than using reflection ! Nice !

Comment: The CPU_ABI* constants have been deprecated in favor of SUPPORTED_*ABIS but these constants work in pretty much the same way and are still part of the Build object,

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class:

`import android.os.Build;`

and then read:

`Build.CPU_ABI`

Comment: This is a complete answer, but [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17134383/104223) was already suggested over a year ago.  Please take the time to review the previous answers before posting :)

Comment: @Leigh This answer is different (more efficient and more future-proof) to the one provided by shem. IMO this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can use adb command

adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi2

and refer the [site]: [How to know a process of an app is 32-bit or 64-bit programmatically in Android lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121199/how-to-know-a-process-of-an-app-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-programmatically-in-android)

If you're looking for the Lollipop API

```
import android.os.Build;

Log.i(TAG, "CPU_ABI : " + Build.CPU_ABI);
Log.i(TAG, "CPU_ABI2 : " + Build.CPU_ABI2);
Log.i(TAG, "OS.ARCH : " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));

Log.i(TAG, "SUPPORTED_ABIS : " + Arrays.toString(Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS));
Log.i(TAG, "SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS : " + Arrays.toString(Build.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS));
Log.i(TAG, "SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS : " + Arrays.toString(Build.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS));
```

Comment: Use a check like the one below to decide which API you'll use:    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

Answer (score 12):

Try this command:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
```

It tells whether cpu is ARM or Intel( 64 or 86_64 respectively )

Comment: How is developer able to run `adb` command on users smartphones?

Comment: adb not  designed to be called from device .. it's basically debugging tool from PC to device/emulator. what you need to access console through app. I think there are limitation and you may need root .. if you need to get this info from app I recommend you to use other approach

Answer (score 6):

The values you are looking for are

> ro.product.cpu.abi

and

> ro.product.cpu.abi2

These can be got using internal api SystemProperties.get So you will have to use Reflection on SystemProperties.

You could use the function getSystemProperty if you are not too keen on reflection. Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796562/read-modem-firmware-version-android/11824150#11824150)

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

`termux-app` uses a different approach and has an explanation:

```
private static String determineTermuxArchName() {
    // Note that we cannot use System.getProperty("os.arch") since that may give e.g. "aarch64"
    // while a 64-bit runtime may not be installed (like on the Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo).
    // Instead we search through the supported abi:s on the device, see:
    // http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html
    // Note that we search for abi:s in preferred order (the ordering of the
    // Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS list) to avoid e.g. installing arm on an x86 system where arm
    // emulation is available.
    for (String androidArch : Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS) {
        switch (androidArch) {
            case "arm64-v8a": return "aarch64";
            case "armeabi-v7a": return "arm";
            case "x86_64": return "x86_64";
            case "x86": return "i686";
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to determine arch from Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS =  " +
        Arrays.toString(Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS));
}
```

From: https://github.com/termux/termux-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/termux/app/TermuxInstaller.java

Answer (score 2):

My Code looks like this

```
private String cpuinfo()
{
String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");    
String arc = arch.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
String rarc="";
if (arc.equals("ARM")) {
    rarc= "This is ARM";
    }else if (arc.equals("MIP")){
        rarc= "This is MIPS";
    }else if (arc.equals("X86")){
        rarc= "This is X86";
    }
    return rarc;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me armeabi-v7a & armeabi-v7a-neon are same or different cpu arch??

Comment: NEON is a specific feature which CPUs can support. If you only want to check if the CPU is ARM, use `System.getProperty("os.arch").toLowerCase().contains("arm")`.

Answer (score 0):

see this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build#SUPPORTED_ABIS

```
Build.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS;
```