# Running ffmpeg commands from android ffmpeg syntax error in logcat

Tags: android, ffmpeg, ubuntu-11.10

I have successfully compiled ffmpeg for android and have ported it.

I placed

1. libffmpeg.so in **/system/lib** directory
2. ffmpeg executable in **/system/bin** and **/system/xbin** directory (i was not sure where to place it). i directly copied ffmpeg executable from source directory (Not sure whether it's a correct way)

Now i am executing commands from android with following code !!

```
imports *
public class LatestActivity extends Activity {

    private Process process;
    String command,text;

    static { 
        System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
    }

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_latest);

          //Execute Command !!  
          try {
               Execute();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }




public void Execute() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        try {
            File dir=new File("/system/bin");
            String[] cmd= {"ffmpeg","-codecs"};

            process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null,dir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("Process IOException starts:",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("System Manual exit !!",e.getMessage());
            System.exit(MODE_PRIVATE);
        }

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()),16384);

         BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

           // read the output from the command
           Log.d("Application output: ","Output if any !"); 
            while ((text = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("Output: ",text); //$NON-NLS-1$
               }


        text="";
           // read any errors from the attempted command
        Log.d("Application output: ","Errors if any !");  //$NON-NLS-1$
           while ((text = stdError.readLine()) != null) {

               Log.d("Error: ",text);  //$NON-NLS-1$
           }



           stdInput.close();
           stdError.close();

           process.waitFor();
           process.getOutputStream().close();
           process.getInputStream().close();
           process.getErrorStream().close(); 
           destroyProcess(process);
           //process.destroy();

    }

    private static void destroyProcess(Process process) {
        try {
            if (process != null) {
                // use exitValue() to determine if process is still running.
                process.exitValue();
            }
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
            // process is still running, kill it.
            process.destroy();
        }
    }

  }
```

And Here is the logcat output:

```
09-05 15:29:13.287: D/dalvikvm(2670): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libffmpeg.so 0x44e7e910, skipping init
09-05 15:29:29.117: I/global(2670): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
09-05 15:29:29.117: D/Application output:(2670): Output if any !
09-05 15:29:29.117: D/Application output:(2670): Errors if any !
09-05 15:29:29.127: D/Error:(2670): /system/bin/ffmpeg: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

m neither getting any errors nor output of command. 
At the end it shows syntax error.
 I want to know what kind of syntax error it is. how to tackle it?

m i doing something wrong?

Comment: can you add the code for ffmpeg file as well?
I mean the file that you refer here:

System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");

Comment: You don't need to load libfmpeg in this scenario. I suggest that you first try to run `/system/bin/ffmpeg -codecs` from ADB shell command line, maybe your binary has some problems

Answer (score 4):

This Error occurs if the ffmpeg file does not compiled for your cpu architechture.

Your commands might be right but you need to find correct ffmpeg file.

Answer (score 1):

**FIXED**
@Gaganpreet Singh
You are right after so much research on this, I have got to know that CPU Chip-set matters too, FFMPEG commands doesn't support INTEL ATOM processor.
Asus Memo Pad 7 using INTEL ATOM cpu chip-set and when trying running ffmpeg command on it, it crashes and throw error  "**SYNTAX ERROR**"

My commands working perfectly on all the devices except the device using INTEL ATOM chipset.

Please review [this](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1894) and [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/creating-a-hardware-decoder-integrating-ffmpeg-with-mediacodec-for-intel-atom-based-android) link if it will be helpful for you.
If anyone finds a solution. Please share with us.

**Finally Fixed this issue**  by creating ffmpeg lib for x64 & armv7 using NDK. And used this Library in my Andriod project. Now I have 2 lib and using this lib for different Android CPU ARCH.
Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344354/1071545) link too. Very helpful.