# openCV 3 remove unnecessary cpu architectures for Android

Tags: android, opencv

After adding openCV 3.0 as library in Android Studio, I observed my apk file has grown to above 50MB, which is obviously not ideal.

Unzipping the apk file revealed that there are multiple target architectures in the `lib` directory, namely `arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, mips64, x86, x86_64`. Each of them occupies 10+MB.

Is it safe to remove some of the target architectures from my source `jniLibs` directory to reduce the apk size? If so, which targets should I remove? I am targeting relatively new devices so as long as it runs on newer devices I am fine with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general ranking of architectures by popularity would be ARM, x86, and then MIPS. The problem is that 64-bit is future facing so depending on how willing you are to give them up means that your 32-bit code on a 64-bit architecture might take some performance hit.

Alternatively use [Multiple APK](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) support in Google Play to deliver the correct architecture's APK to your user to reduce size/download time at the cost of the associated complexity.

**Updated**

Support for 32-bit code on 64-bit architectures is mandated by the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf) Section 3.3.1

```
MUST support the equivalent 32-bit ABI if any 64-bit ABI is supported
```

Google doesn't want new 64-bit devices to break on 32-bit binaries as there is quite a bit of 32-bit code in the ecosystem (i.e. games).

Comment: So if I remove `x86_64`, then the app would still work on `x86_64` if I have `x86`? I wouldn't mind some performance drop since it is not the main feature.

Comment: for arm which has `arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a`, it is safe to remove `arm64-v8a`? If so, which one would be considered the 32-bit equivalent?

Comment: You can remove `arm64-v8a`. Actually both `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` are 32-bit. The first one is for older ARMv6 while the latter is for ARMv7. Most newer phones are ARMv7. While the Play store should exclude `armeabi` if you don't include it, I would put in a check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989629/api-call-to-get-processor-architecture and tell the user that it won't run on that device.