# Android - How to identify if device is ARM 64

Tags: android, arm, android-hardware

I am facing few library errors on new Android ARM 64 devices, is there a way to identify ARM 64 devices so that I can bypass my code for those particular devices?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API call to get processor architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989629/api-call-to-get-processor-architecture)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily get this through `Build` api of android.
`Build.CPU_ABI` gives `armeabi-v7` in my device

you can look at following docs for help

[ABI management](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa)

[Build API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI)