# Is there a way to distinguish Android Arm os from the Android x86 os in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, user-agent, android-x86, os-detection

To detect the Android OS, we could search the navigator.userAgent string for the 'Android' key word.

However, my question is how to detect whether it's an Android Arm device or an Android X86 device?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

Original post: [API call to get processor architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989629/api-call-to-get-processor-architecture)

Comment: Nope, I want a solution in JavaScript.